# Even or odd solutions to Maxwell/Schrodinger equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, symmetry, normal-modes

The solutions to the source free Maxwells equations in a photonic cavity (or equally the solutions to the Schrödinger equation) can be even or odd; $u(x) = u(-x)$ or $u(x) = - u(-x)$ or neither. But what are the boundary conditions giving rise to the symmetry of these modes and is it possible to design a system with only even or only odd modes?

It seems that a centrally symmetric potential (such as the square well) gives even and odd modes but is there a further condition that can separate the two, for instance an asymmetric potential?

Comment: Do you mean, specifically, odd and even about the *center* of the system? Because you can always shift your coordinate system so that $x=0$ is at the left end of the system, in which case you'll generally only get odd modes (about $x=0$) (for, e.g., the particle in a box). Can you clarify your question? The even-ness or oddness of the solutions in 1D is a consequence of the fact that the systems in question display parity symmetry (i.e., symmetry under reflection through $x=0$, or more generally the center of the system).

Comment: @march Yes, I mean even and odd with respect to the centre. So would a lop sided square well give only odd solutions? And also, do simple electromagnetic systems have only odd modes when the system is not invariant under $\pi$ rotation?

Answer (score 0):

A PDE on a symmetric interval $(-a,a)$ with a symmetric operator with respect to parity operator $P: x\to -x, \partial_x \to -\partial_x$ is not essentially selfadjoint, because boundary conditions are not specified. As a simple example consider $-\Delta f = \lambda ^2 f$ with boundary value $f(-a)=0, f'(a)=0$. The complete basis of eigenstates is

$$f_n(x) = \sin\left((2n+1) \ \pi \frac{x+a}{4 a}\right)$$

[image: asymmetric basis]

This basis makes very slow approximations of a simple sin

$$\int_{-3}^3 \sin(x/(6 ) \pi]\sin((2 n+1) \pi/12 (x+3))  dx  \to 1/n$$

the reason for the $1/n$ convergence rate  that, as a periodic function on $mathbb R$, it has jump discontinuties.

Such bases are eg used for spin states on the 2-sphere as eigenfunction set between the poles, the reason why spin dynamics breaks the parity invariance in $\mathbb R^3$

Its one example that free particle Hilbert spaces may all be isomorphic (equal), but not equally suitable to describe interacting systems.

In QFT with Hilbert spaces over denumerably dimensional manifolds this phenomenon generates the famous statement, that an intercting QFT has no convergent approximation by states in the free QF basis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, I cannot find anything valuable there. I canceled my account here because of such comments. They even accused me of using GPT with a ban for one week. Most areas  areas in mathematical physics cannot expalained to the beginners. Such texts are readable only at a theoretical masters level.  On has to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the actual physical boundary conditions. I quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(physics):

Where the nodes occur in relation to the boundary reflecting the waves depends on the end conditions or boundary conditions. Although there are many types of end conditions, the ends of resonators are usually one of two types that cause total reflection:

**Fixed boundary**: Examples of this type of boundary are the attachment point of a guitar string, the closed end of an open pipe like an organ pipe, or a woodwind pipe, the periphery of a drumhead, a transmission line with the end short circuited, or the mirrors at the ends of a laser cavity. In this type, the amplitude of the wave is forced to zero at the boundary, so there is a node at the boundary, and the other nodes occur at multiples of half a wavelength from it:
0,  λ/2,  λ,  3λ/2,  2λ, ..., nλ/2

**Free boundary:** Examples of this type are an open-ended organ or woodwind pipe, the ends of the vibrating resonator bars in a xylophone, glockenspiel or tuning fork, the ends of an antenna, or a transmission line with an open end. In this type the derivative (slope) of the wave's amplitude (in sound waves the pressure, in electromagnetic waves, the current) is forced to zero at the boundary. So there is an amplitude maximum (antinode) at the boundary, the first node occurs a quarter wavelength from the end, and the other nodes are at half wavelength intervals from there:
λ/4,  3λ/4,  5λ/4,  7λ/4, ..., (2n+1)λ/4